# Uncertain behavior of hand eye calibration

Tags: ros, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I am collecting samples from different pose for move it hand-eye calibration. Instead of solving it shows the far position of my camera after solving sample 5  as shown in the picture. Am I forgetting some steps?

[image: image description]

What my robot looks like is described in the below image.

[image: image description]

On the six-axis, I have attached an Iron rod and at the end of that rod, there is tool0 (My tool point). In the iron rod, after 10 cm from the axis-six, I have kept the camera at 3.5cm height(Z+ from the rod.).

I don't know the issue, Is something wrong with my configuration or the issue is with the hand-eye calibration?

The hand-eye calibration setting is described below.
[image: image description]

[image: image description]

Thanks for the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377837/uncertain-behavior-of-hand-eye-calibration/) by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1622 on 2021-05-06

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks, @Piotr for this answer.

We did some hand-eye calibration but we got mixed results. You might want to try to:

1. Increase the separation between ArUco makers. I think 1 mm is to small of a gap. Our board had a 1cm gap. Also we've noticed that the bigger the markers are the better camera position estimate.
2. Try different software. We used this package: https://github.com/IFL-CAMP/easy_handeye. In it you can also find some tips on what kind of robot movements are the best for the calibration process.
3. I'm not sure if I understand the package instruction correctly, but I would try to set, depending on what you want to achieve, the "End-effector frame" as the last link of the robot or as your TCP (create a new frame at the end of the rod). Next roughly measure the distance of the camera from that point and put it in as the initial guess.

I hope some of this suggestions will help.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0